# Unable to use Parameter in Insert statement in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Taking INS_QUERY value from Audit table.

```
 INS_QUERY = ("INSERT INTO sales.dbo.Customer_temp (ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,CITY,COUNTRY,PHONE) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3],d[4],d[5]))

 cursor = cs.cursor()

 cursor.execute(INS_QUERY)

 cs.commit();
```

if I hard coded the INS_QUERY value in script it's working fine but if I take same value from table it's giving below error message.

Error Message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT INTO
>   sales.dbo.Customer_temp (ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,CITY,COUNTRY,PHONE)
>   VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Audit Table Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO DBO.AUDIT_TABLE(INST_QUERY) VALUES ('("INSERT INTO sales.dbo.Customer_temp (ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,CITY,COUNTRY,PHONE) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")" % (d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3],d[4],d[5]))')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pyodbc connector and the parameters syntax is **?**, not **%s**
The second detail is that when the parameters are from type str, there is no need to use single quotes **'?'**, this is done for you automatically.

Can you try this approach and tell me how it works for you?

```
INS_QUERY = "INSERT INTO sales.dbo.Customer_temp (ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,CITY,COUNTRY,PHONE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor = cs.cursor()
cursor.execute(INS_QUERY, (d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3],d[4],d[5]) )
cs.commit();
```

Comment: @Harisha You have to copy the row with the `INS_QUERY` from my answer exactly. There is no such thing as `('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')` in it instead we have `(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`
Can you give it another try?

Comment: Giving below error by excuting above statment whatever you were provided,                                                                                                       cursor.execute(INS_QUERY, (d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 6 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: @Harisha I edited my answer - please give it another try, since you are using pyodbc.

Comment: @iBug I will for sure add a detailed explanation, but first I want to make sure that the code actually works!